# Comparing two compass bearings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two compass bearings (0-360 degrees):

```
var routeDirection = 28
var windDirection = 289
```

I need to compare these bearings to determine if the rider is going to get a

a) cross wind

b) tail wind

c) head wind

I tried converting the bearings to compass directions, eg:

```
  var compass = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW', 'N'];
  var windDirection = compass[Math.round(bearing / 22.5)];
```

and then doing a basic string comparison:

```
if (routeDirection=='N') && (windDirection=='S') {
 output = 'Headwind'
}
```

But obviously this is verbose and inefficient...

Comment: Could you add some more info about your desired result? E.g. how closely must the wind direction match the route direction for the result to show headwind? Is within 22.5 degrees?

Comment: Yes, 22.5 degrees would be fine. I have a wind speed variable, which I will use to say strong head wing, slight tail wind etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do direct comparisons between the route direction and wind direction, and determine the type of wind based on the difference:

```
if(routeDirection > windDirection)
    var difference = routeDirection - windDirection;
else
    var difference = windDirection - routeDirection;

// left/right not important, so only need parallel (0) or antiparallel (180)
difference = difference - 180;
//keep value positive for comparison check
if(difference < 0)
    difference = difference * -1;

if(difference <= 45) // wind going in roughly the same direction, up to you and your requirements
    output = "headwind";
elseif(difference <= 135) // cross wind
    output = "crosswind";
elseif (difference <= 180)
    output = "tailwind";
else
    output = "something has gone wrong with the calculation...";
```

The above calculation means you're not performing comparisons on each compass point, only the *relative* difference in heading of the boat and the wind, reducing the verbosity. It also allows for multiple angle comparisons by using smaller degree steps and adding more elseifs.  This could also be done with a switch(), but would come out with a similar code line count.

Comment: thank you, this works will for me. It also makes it easier to add more variations

Comment: If this is your accepted answer, it helps if you tick the "accept answer" button (looks like a tick-mark next to the voting value).

Comment: Sorry, I am getting the opposite results e.g if i am riding west and the wind direction is east it should return as a headwind, but it returns as a tailwind. see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/luIxj

Comment: Answer edited; I just swapped "headwind" and "tailwind" around.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're going straight up, you'd have this:

```
\ Head wind /
 \         /
  \       /
   \  |  /
    \ | /
Cross\|/Winds
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
  /       \
 /         \
/ Tail wind \
```

So basically... first you rotate your point of view so that you're travelling at bearing 0:

```
var adjustedWindDirection = windDirection - routeDirection;
```

Of course, a bearing should be in the range 0-360, so adjust again:

```
adjustedWindDirection = (adjustedWindDirection+360)%360;
```

Now we need to figure out which quadrant the direction is in:

```
var quadrant = Math.round((adjustedWindDirection-45)/90);
```

Finally:

```
var winds = ["head","cross (left)","tail","cross (right)"];
var resultingWind = winds[quadrant];
```

Done!

Comment: thank you, very well explained. I am however getting the opposite results e.g a tail, when it should be a head wind. See here:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mkbgA